# How to load an SVG and a referenced PNG from a REST service at the same time?

Tags: rest, svg, png

I'm trying to create a web service in PHP that can deliver an SVG with reference to a PNG raster image. Both the data for the SVG as well as the binary PNG image come from a MySQL database on the server.

**Option A**: Encode the PNG data in base-64 and embed it directly in the SVG, such as:

```
<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
```

*Concerns*: 30% heavier load than loading it as pure binary and noticeable delay when loading it with Postman (or is this just because of Postman).

**Option B**: Call the PNG data as binary and save it as a file on the file system, then call the SVG file, which would then reference the physical PNG file.

*Concerns*: Involvement of the file system (which implies I need to start managing physical files, expiration dates etc).

Is there perhaps another way that an SVG can reference the binary data on the fly without it having to be on the file system?

Comment: In the end, I simply made a call to another REST service to deliver me the binary data. The only "draw-back" is really that the SVG is delivered (and visualized) first, then the raster layer. Adding an "onload" event to the image (for example to switch the SVG to visible) is not sufficiently supported across all browsers. But for now, it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish something similar (in my case sending data for SVGs with additional data about each file as binary files, which are much smaller than sending xml, text, or json) - I use CBOR. In my case, I compress the SVG using LZString compression first, and add this along with additional data attributes to a JSON object. Then I convert the JSON object to CBOR. I think CBOR can handle your base 64 data without any need for conversion - more information about it is here: [cbor.io](http://cbor.io/)

I found a PHP library for CBOR here: https://github.com/2tvenom/CBOREncode

This may not be the way to go at all for you, but I thought I'd throw it out there just in case.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, I will take a look. It could also be that my question is a "best practices" question and it depends on a lot of factors (e.g. speed of database retrieval, type of file storage), so it's going to be a long string of trial and error.

Comment: I wanted a "database free" setup, so for me the CBOR has worked great, loading thousands of files with their associated data with no DB at all. I just created an alphabetic directory file for each letter, which keeps track of the files in that folder. Best of luck to you - let me know if you want any more details about my setup ok?